# Clear the errors once input field is valid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I'm using AngularJS with node.js. I've implemented error handler as follows:

#### node router effect.js:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){

    req.checkBody('name', 'Effect name is required.').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    console.log(errors);

    if(errors) {
        res.status(500).json(errors);
        return;
    }

    var effect = new Effect({
        name: req.body.name
    });

    Effect.createEffect(effect, function(err, result) {
        if(err) { next(err) }
        res.status(201).end();
    });

});
```

#### effectController.js:

```
$scope.submit = function(effect) {

    effectService.save(effect, function(err, result, status) {

        $scope.errors = err;

        if(err == null) {
            $scope.effect = null;
            if(!(effect == null || effect == undefined)) {
                if(!(effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '')) { 
                    $location.path('/effect');
                }
            }
            reload();
        }

    });

}
```

#### effectService.js

```
function save(effect, callback) {
    if(effect == undefined || effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '') {
        $http.post('/api/effect', effect)
             .success(function(data, status) {
                callback(null, data);
             })
             .error(function(data, status) {
                var errors = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var err = data[i];
                    var param, msg;
                    for(var key in err){
                        if(key == 'param') param = err[key];
                        if(key == 'msg') msg = err[key];
                    }
                    errors[param] = msg;
                }
                callback(errors, null);
             });
    } else {
        $http.put('/api/effect/' + effect._id, effect);
    }
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<form novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{ 'has-error': errors.fname }">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control form-input" ng-model="effect.name"
                   ng-disabled="isReadOnly" required />
            <p class="help-block" ng-model="errors.name" ng-show="(errors == null || errors == undefined) ? false : errors.name">Effect name is required</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
            <div class="form-group form-controls">
                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-input submit" ng-click="submit(effect)" ng-hide="isReadOnly">Save</button>
                <button id="clear" class="btn btn-input clear" ng-class="isReadOnly ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-danger'" ng-click="clear()">{{clearButtonText}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

-> This works as expected.

**Problem:**

When there is an error from server, the error is displayed on the page. But error does not go away as soon as the input is valid. In short I want that errors should go away as soon as the input field is valid. I don't want the user to click submit button to clear the errors.

**Update:**

I have implemented another validation for duplicates in server as follows:

index.js file:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
        duplicateRecord: function(input, propertyName, collection) {
            var duplicateRecordFound = false;
            collection.forEach(function(element) {
                if (element.propertyName == input) {
                    duplicateRecordFound = true;
                    return;
                }
            }, this);
            return duplicateRecordFound;
        }
    }
}));
```

router effect.js file:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){

    Effect.find(function(err, effects) {

        if(err){
            next(err);
        }

        req.checkBody('name', 'Effect name is required.').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('name', 'Duplicate effect name.').duplicateRecord('name', effects);
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        console.log(errors);

        if(errors) {
            res.status(500).json(errors);
            return;
        }

        var effect = new Effect({
            name: req.body.name
        });

        Effect.createEffect(effect, function(err, result) {
            if(err) { next(err) }
            res.status(201).end();
        });

    });

});
```

Also I changed the angular controller as @lean suggested:

```
$scope.validate = function () {
    if($scope.errors != undefined)
    {
        if (angular.isDefined($scope.effect.name) && $scope.effect.name.length > 0) {
            $scope.errors.showName = false;
        } else {
            $scope.errors.showName = true;
        }
    }
}

$scope.submit = function(effect) {

    effectService.save(effect, function(err, result, status) {

        $scope.errors = err;

        if(err == null) {
            $scope.effect = null;
            if(!(effect == null || effect == undefined)) {
                if(!(effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '')) { 
                    $location.path('/effect');
                }
            }
            reload();
        } else {
            $scope.errors.showName = true;
        }

    });
```

Also I changed paragraph element in html file as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control form-input" ng-model="effect.name"
       ng-change="validate()" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" required />
<p class="help-block" ng-model="errors.name" ng-show="(errors == null || errors == undefined) ? false : (errors.showName)">{{errors.name}}</p>
```

**Problem:**

When I enter a name of the effect in input and then click on submit button, then if the name of the effect already exists in database then I get a message saying `Duplicate Effect name`. Then if I change a character in input box then error message goes away. Up to this point it works fine. But then if I delete all the text in input box, then the error message displayed is again `Duplicate Effect name.` instead of `Effect name is required.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ng-change` on your input to call a validator function like `validate()` in this example.

#### View

```
<form novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{ 'has-error': errors.name }">
            <input type="text"
                   id="name"
                   name="name"
                   class="form-control form-input"
                   ng-model="effect.name"
                   ng-change="validate()"
                   ng-disabled="isReadOnly" 
                   required />
            <p class="help-block" ng-model="errors.name" ng-show="(errors == null || errors == undefined) ? false : errors.name">Effect name is required</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
            <div class="form-group form-controls">
                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-input submit" ng-click="submit(effect)" ng-hide="isReadOnly">Save</button>
                <button id="clear" class="btn btn-input clear" ng-class="isReadOnly ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-danger'" ng-click="clear()">{{clearButtonText}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Validation $scope function

```
//init scopes
$scope.errors = {};
$scope.effect = {
  name: ''
}

/**
 * Manually validate fields
 */
$scope.validate = function () {
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.effect.name) && $scope.effect.name.length > 0) {
        $scope.errors.name = false;
    } else {
        $scope.errors.name = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I had to go out of the town for some other work. I have tried to implement your answer and it works well for such simple validation like required. But I need more. I mean if I am validating a property called name from the server such that name of the effect should not be a duplicate. In this case I cannot accomplish this task from client side only. I need to check that from server side. So, when I click on save button, if the effect name already exists in database then I should get an error. Then when I change the name, the error should go away.

Comment: @Vishal you should implement a client side & servside validation so. Create a callback from the server which specifiies the error (e.g. empty|noUnique) `{ error: true, fields: [{ name: 'name', errors: [{ empty: true, unique: true }]}]}` . Creating an answer for such handling would be to much, sorry. Unable to create working answer with an server-side-validation here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes that you suggested. But still I have some problems. For more information please check the update part in question.